# multiple res folders doesn't show inside android studio's project window

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

I declared multiple resource folders as the attached image below, It worked fine on Android Studio 3.1. But after upgrading to version 3.2.1 Android Studio didn't show me my custom res folders in the project window, although I still can build without any error. anyone here can help me? thanks

Please see [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJkIp.png)

Comment: Hi, U have not a stable version. plz Upgrade From help>Update or get from https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: Because of security concerns, many people will not click a link(without description) on SO. Please consider replacing the link with the image.

Comment: hi @sanaebadi I'm using the latest stable version 3.2.1

Answer (score -1):

The sub folders in the fig isn't generated automatically after gradle, which should be created manually.
plz ref [Create source sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets)